# Mutt open mailbox

Tags: mutt

When I start Mutt, the default mailbox is whatever is in the $MAIL environment variable.

How can I startup Mutt, pointing to a different mailbox rather than $MAIL, or better still, how can I change the current mailbox from within Mutt?

I have a clue as to using a [.muttrc](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-3.html#ss3.11) file.  Is there an example of a .muttrc which can open multiple inboxes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I do is set the `MAIL` environment variable to point to my mailbox. That way the setting applies to other programs (e.g. shells that show “you have new mail”). But you can do it from `.muttrc` as well:

```
set spoolfile = "/path/to/mailbox"
```

To start mutt showing a different mailbox as a one-off, run `mutt -f /alternate/mailbox`. Within mutt, type **`c`** to change to a different mailbox. After `c`, you can type the path to the mailbox, or you can use one of the shortcuts (see “Mailbox shortcuts” in the manual) such as **`!`** to refer to `spoolfile` (or `$MAIL`) and **`=foo`** to refer to `$folder/foo` where `$folder` is defined in your `.muttrc` as

```
set spool = "/path/to/directory/containing/mailboxes"
```

If receive mail in several mailboxes and would like mutt to tell you when you receive mail in any of them, look up “Monitoring incoming mail” in the manual; basically you need to add this to your `.muttrc`:

```
mailboxes "/mailbox/to/watch" "/other/mailbox/to/watch"
```